# "requires" ignores a field is not static

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int fun(int const&) { return 5; }
struct T { int x; };

int main() {
  std::cout << fun(T::x) << std::endl;                   // Line A
  std::cout << requires { fun(T::x); } << std::endl;     // Line B
}
```

If I only comment Line B, then the code cannot be compiled (as expected, since `x` is not static in `T`). But when I only comment Line A, the code compiles just fine with both Clang 11.0.0 and GCC 10.2.0 (both output `1`). What it is that I am missing about `requires`? shouldn't it return `false`?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `fun` in the example? Seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: What is the alternative? `T::x` is valid. So `requires` should return true. I want to make it fail because `x` is not `static` in `T`.

Comment: `T::x` isn't valid, unless its address is taken or used in an unevaluated context.

Comment: I don't see any problem with `T::x`. Of course you cannot expect to pass `T::x` to a function since `x` is not static. But for example, `using A = decltype(T::x);` compiles just fine.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/feT3qP). You're not allowed to access `T::x` generally, there's nothing special about it being a function argument.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, "Of course you cannot expect to pass T::x to a function since x is not static". Your example "std::cout << T::x" passes `T::x` to a function. Just because, `T::x` cannot be used in one example, it does not make it invalid. Again `using A = decltype(T::x);` is a valid statement and can be compiled just fine.

Answer (score 2):

A requires expression is one big list of unevaluated operands.

> **[expr.prim.req]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.req#2) A requires-expression is a prvalue of type bool whose value is
> described below. Expressions appearing within a requirement-body are
> unevaluated operands.

And a qualified-id naming a non-static data member always could appear in an unevaluated operand.

> **[expr.prim.id]**
>
> [2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prim.id#2) An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or
> non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member ([expr.unary.op]), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand. [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S {
>   int m;
> };
> int i = sizeof(S::m);           // OK
> int j = sizeof(S::m + 42);      // OK
> ```
>
> — end example ]

The unevaluated operand where `T::x` may appear can be any expression. So even pre-C++20 you could for example write

```
decltype(fun(T::x)) i{};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is there any `concept` that can decide if `x` is static in `T` or a member? Assuming either `x` is a static variable or `x` is a non-static variable (if it is of any help, we also know type of `x` is `U`, which could be a reference).

Comment: @Koosha - Well... you can always leverage the fact that `decltype(&T::x)` will be different  for the two. For a static member, it will be a pointer, and for a non-static member it will be a pointer-to-member. Examine that with the help of `std::is_pointer` or `std::is_member_pointer` and you can differentiate.

Comment: Ah... references make this more complex. If `U` can be a reference, I have nothing. I'm not sure how `decltype(&T::x)` would need to behave.

Comment: Yes, if `U` is a reference, I get the error `cannot create pointer to reference member T::x` (even when I do `&T::x` within Line B).

Comment: So, to summarise, a common, intuitive understanding that you can check whether a piece of code will compile with `requires` is incorrect.